# Enable SSL for ASP .NET Site

Tags: asp.net, ssl, iis-express

I am trying to enable SSL on one of my ASP .NET Web Site.

While doing so I am performing below two steps.

[image]

[image]

After doing above two settings if i try to browse site I should see below two popup.

[image]
[image]

But I am not getting above two popup instead I am getting below message on IE.

This page can’t be displayed

- Make sure the web address https://localhost:2698 is correct.
- Look for the page with your search engine.
- Refresh the page in a few minutes.

*Note: Please ignore PortNumber I have taken screen from other website.*

Comment: You'll need to put the generated certificate in the Trusted Root certificate store.

Comment: @gretro Can you please help me with some link where I can get step by step instructions to do so?

Comment: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sbs/2008/05/08/installing-a-self-signed-certificate-as-a-trusted-root-ca-in-windows-vista/

Comment: @gretro I am browsing with localhost not with host header. The link which you shared is for host header. I am following steps mentioned here.  http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/aspnet-and-web-tools-20132-preview-for-visual-studio-2013-release-notes#ssl

Answer (score 1):

If they don't appear, then you've probably clicked "Don't ask me again", and VS is doing exactly what you asked it to do - not ask you.

You can reset that by editing the registry and removing
    `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\WebProjects\HideTrustIISCertificatePrompt`

Then when you restart VS and attempt to enable SSL on your project you should be prompted again.